# how to find holes in image and fill it using opencv python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to identify holes in the image and fill it based on neighbor color pixels.
suppose if Image is as shown below

[image1](https://imgur.com/a/CUxZPzX)

till now I'm able to identify holes space region but not completely fill without leaving any border lines, my approach code is as below

```
img=cv2.imread(r'image.png')
img_copy = img.copy()
black_MIN = np.array([0, 0, 0],np.uint8)
black_MAX = np.array([179, 50, 100],np.uint8)

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, black_MIN, black_MAX)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(frame_threshed, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)  # Area of first contour

    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(c, True)  
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * perimeter, True)
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    roi=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cv2.rectangle(img_copy,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,252,213),-1)
plt.imshow(img_copy[:,:,::-1])
```

first i'm finding contours based on black region tresholding then i'm filling them as shown in below image

[image2](https://imgur.com/a/CUxsPLX)

with this i'm not able to completely fill the holes, only rectangle part of the contours getting filled as shown in image, what I expecting is as shown in below image
[image3](https://imgur.com/a/CUxZPLa)

How can I modify my code to get image as shown above? any help or suggestion to make this possible will be highly appreciated

Comment: It seems like in the `frame_threshed` step you've already identified all of the black parts of the image. Why convert that into a contour? I would stay in a pixel representation the entire way.

Comment: PS: I can't reproduce your output from the code provided.

Comment: why are you doing this on a __picture__ of a CAD model, instead of the model itself (mesh/geometry processing)? https://xyproblem.info/ -- this basically looks like inpainting. to find the holes (to inpaint), you might wanna use some dilation on the connected components representing holes. that'll remove stray wireframe wires and cut a little off the borders of each hole

Comment: @NickODell tx for writing, doing this I don't get coordinates of surrounding boundary region of non black pixel , if i replace only black pixel this will leave the boundary line mark not solid color so only finding contour

Comment: @xyproblem.info i'm doing some image processing on images obtained from CAD models to automate something for that ive to solve this problem of holes